# Can Python Bottle and CGI (or fastCGI) on IIS 7.5 be used for Production?

Tags: python, cgi, iis-7.5, fastcgi, bottle

I am using Bottle and running it from the command prompt, the built in server.  When I deploy it I see no mention of IIS in the documentation:

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html

I understand that it is not really made with IIS in mind, but Microsoft has an article:

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/276494?wa=wsignin1.0

With all this in mind, can Bottle be run on IIS 7.5 - for **Production**?

I have seen some questions on SO and elsewhere about fastCGI an Python, but I do not know if that is for Production.

Note, I do not wish to use IronPython.  Other than the Python interpreter, I'd like to use as much MS IIS, natively, as possible (I have to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience has been with Apache (on Linux and Windows).  The article you refer to gives an example for ActiveState Python (which, by the way, is what I use on Windows) and is applicable for running Python cgi scripts rather than fastcgi.  So if you want to run fastcgi under IIS (assuming that fastcgi is an option with IIS), you will have to look elsewhere on how to do that.

But to answer your question: Yes, since IIS does support Python cgi scripts, you can run your Bottle application for sure in that mode.  For example:

```
from bottle import Bottle
app = Bottle()

app.route('/')
def hello():
   return 'Hello!'

app.run(server='cgi')
```

If you find a way of configuring IIS for fastcgi, then I would suggest you install *flup* and then code:

```
from bottle import Bottle
app = Bottle()

app.route('/')
def hello():
   return 'Hello!'

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
WSGIServer(app).run()
```

Anyway, the above two examples work under Apache for cgi and fastcgi respectively.  I might point out that I have experienced a problem with my output being truncated on Windows when running cgi under apache.  Whether this will be a problem under IIS, you will find out. See [Truncated output using Python bottle 0.12.8 as a CGI application under Windows on an Apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248570/truncated-output-using-python-bottle-0-12-8-as-a-cgi-application-under-windows-o)